# Querying Multi Level Nested fields on Elastic Search

Tags: nosql, nested, elasticsearch, pyes

I'm new to Elastic Search and to the non-SQL paradigm.
I've been following ES tutorial, but there is one thing I couldn't put to work.

In the following code (I'me using [PyES](http://packages.python.org/pyes/) to interact with ES) I create a single document, with a nested field (subjects), that contains another nested field (concepts).

```
from pyes import *

conn = ES('127.0.0.1:9200')  # Use HTTP

# Delete and Create a new index.
conn.indices.delete_index("documents-index")
conn.create_index("documents-index")

# Create a single document.
document = {
    "docid": 123456789,
    "title": "This is the doc title.",
    "description": "This is the doc description.",
    "datepublished": 2005,
    "author": ["Joe", "John", "Charles"],
    "subjects": [{
                    "subjectname": 'subject1',
                    "subjectid": [210, 311, 1012, 784, 568],
                    "subjectkey": 2,
                    "concepts": [
                                    {"name": "concept1", "score": 75},
                                    {"name": "concept2", "score": 55}
                                  ]
                },
                {
                    "subjectname": 'subject2',
                    "subjectid": [111, 300, 141, 457, 748],
                    "subjectkey": 0,
                    "concepts": [
                                    {"name": "concept3", "score": 88},
                                    {"name": "concept4", "score": 55},
                                    {"name": "concept5", "score": 66}
                                  ]
                }],
    }


# Define the nested elements.
mapping1 = {
            'subjects': {
                'type': 'nested'
            }
        }
mapping2 = {
            'concepts': {
                'type': 'nested'
            }
        }
conn.put_mapping("document", {'properties': mapping1}, ["documents-index"])
conn.put_mapping("subjects", {'properties': mapping2}, ["documents-index"])


# Insert document in 'documents-index' index.
conn.index(document, "documents-index", "document", 1)

# Refresh connection to make queries.
conn.refresh()
```

I'm able to query *subjects* nested field:

```
query1 = {
    "nested": {
        "path": "subjects",
        "score_mode": "avg",
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "text": {"subjects.subjectname": "subject1"}
                    },
                    {
                        "range": {"subjects.subjectkey": {"gt": 1}}
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}


results = conn.search(query=query1)
for r in results:
    print r  # as expected, it returns the entire document.
```

but I can't figure out how to query based on *concepts* nested field.

ES [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/nested-query.html) refers that

> Multi level nesting is automatically supported, and detected,
>   resulting in an inner nested query to automatically match the relevant
>   nesting level (and not root) if it exists within another nested query.

So, I tryed to build a query with the following format:

```
query2 = {
        "nested": {
            "path": "concepts",
            "score_mode": "avg",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "text": {"concepts.name": "concept1"}
                        },
                        {
                           "range": {"concepts.score": {"gt": 0}}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
}
```

which returned 0 results.

I can't figure out what is missing and I haven't found any example with queries based on two levels of nesting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, after trying a tone of combinations, I finally got it using the following query:

```
query3 = {
    "nested": {
        "path": "subjects",
        "score_mode": "avg",
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "text": {"subjects.concepts.name": "concept1"}
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, the nested **path** attribute (*subjects*) is always the same, no matter the nested attribute level, and in the query definition I used the attribute's full path (*subject.concepts.name*).

Comment: Since I use only one boolean condition, a more correct query definition would be to use
"query": {"text": {"subjects.concepts.name": "concept1"}}

Answer (score 2):

Shot in the dark since I haven't tried this personally, but have you tried the fully qualified path to Concepts?

```
query2 = {
       "nested": {
           "path": "subjects.concepts",
           "score_mode": "avg",
           "query": {
               "bool": {
                   "must": [
                       {
                           "text": {"subjects.concepts.name": "concept1"}
                       },
                       {
                          "range": {"subjects.concepts.score": {"gt": 0}}
                       }
                   ]
               }
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: I posted my answer without refreshing the page and I didn't see your answer.
It was almost that, the path value should be "subjects" only.

Answer (score 1):

I have some question for JCJS's answer. why your mapping shouldn't like this?

```
mapping = {
    "subjects": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
            "concepts": {
                "type": "nested"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try to define two type-mapping maybe doesn't work, but be a flatten data; I think we should nested in nested properties..

At last... if we use this mapping nested query should like this...

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "subjects.concepts",
            "query": {
                "term": {
                    "name": {
                        "value": "concept1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's vital for using `full path` for path attribute...but not for term key can be full-path or relative-path.